# If $\,p\,$ is prime, is $\,p^n\mathbb{Z}_p=\mathbb{Z}_p\,$ for any positive integer $n$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Is $\,p^n\mathbb{Z}_p=\mathbb{Z}_p\,$ for any positive integer $n\,?$

$\mathbb{Z}_p =$ ring of $p$-adic integers, $\,p$ prime.

Thanks.

Comment: Is $1$ in $p\mathbb Z_p$?

Comment: No, I'm not assuming it is.

Comment: I am not asking what you are assuming. Can you tell at least see if $1$ is or is not in $p\mathbb Z_p$? How do you check if an element is in $p\mathbb Z_p$?

Comment: If $1\in p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$ then for some $x\in \mathbb{Z}_p$, $p^nx=1$. So $p^{-n}=x\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ which is impossible. So $1\nin p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$.  Am I close? Thanks

Comment: *Why* is it not posssible?

Comment: It's because then $v_p(x)<0$?

Comment: Ok. So is $p\mathbb Z_p=\mathbb Z_p$?

Comment: I see, so $p\mathbb{Z}_p$ is strictly contained in $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: You tell me. ${}{}$

Comment: Yes, $p\mathbb{Z}_p\subsetneqq\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Related and possible source of confusion: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/451172/96384 (They are isomorphic as additive groups, but not identical as sets.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to see this is to consider $\mathbb{Q}_p$ as the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to the $p$-adic absolute value $\lvert\cdot\rvert_p$. Then $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is defined as the unit ball inside $\mathbb{Q}_p$. And for $x\in p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$ write
$$
x = p^nz.
$$
Then
$$
\lvert x\rvert_p = \lvert p^n\rvert_p\lvert z\rvert_p  = \frac{1}{p^n}\lvert z\rvert_p\leq \frac{1}{p^n}.
$$
However, you for example have that $\lvert 1\rvert_p = 1$.

You see that $p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$ "gets smaller and smaller" for larger $n$.

Comment: Thanks-- but is it true that $p^n\mathbb{Z}_p\cong\mathbb{Z}_p$ as additive groups?

Comment: @MarkRodriguez: If you have a follow up question, then feel free to just post a new question.

Comment: @MarkRodriguez, as you know, $\mathbb Z_p$ has a unit element. Does $p\mathbb Z_p$ have a unit element?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: I meant to ask if they're isomorphic as additive groups

Answer (score 4):

Think about it:

What must hold if $\;\;p^n\mathbb{Z}_p=\mathbb{Z}_p\quad?$

Is every element in $\mathbb Z_p$ also in $p^n\mathbb Z_p$? Consider, e.g., $1 \in \mathbb Z_p$. Is $1 \in p^n\mathbb Z_p$?  If not, then it certainly cannot hold that $p^n\mathbb{Z}_p=\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: $\huge\color{green}{+}^+\color{blue}{☺}\color{green}{+}^+$ @amWhy

Comment: Listing the elements of $\mathbb Z_p$ is sort of difficult, because it is an uncountable set!