# Is $p^n\mathbb Z_p\cong \mathbb Z_p$ as additive groups?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Is it true that $p^n\mathbb{Z}_p\cong \mathbb Z_p$ as additive groups?

Here $\mathbb Z_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers for $p$ prime and $n$ is any positive integer.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $R$ is any integral domain (unitary commutative ring without zero divisors) and $x\in R$ is any non-zero element, the additive groups of $R$ and of the principal ideal $Rx$ are naturally isomorphic.

Once you have clear a proof in your case, it would be clear how to prove this more general fact and how to generalize it further.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are isomorphic as topological groups. Can you think of a natural homomorphism between them?

Comment: Maybe the map $\mathbb Z_p\longrightarrow p^n\mathbb Z_p$: $(x_1,x_2,...)\mapsto (0,...,0,x_1,x_2,...)$ with the first n entries 0,  where $\mathbb Z_p$ is the inverse limit of the rings $\mathbb Z/p^n \mathbb Z$. Am I close?

Comment: Is the proposed image an element of $p^n\mathbf{Z}_p$? Is it even an element of $\mathbf{Z}_p$? The inverse limit structure is actually irrelevant (aside from continuity), as is made clear by Andrea Mori's answer. Try to do this with $\mathbf{Z}$ in place of $\mathbf{Z}_p$, i.e., to define an isomorphism of abelian groups $\mathbf{Z}\cong p^n\mathbf{Z}$. The map should really be applicable to $\mathbf{Z}_p$ as well, or any torsion-free abelian group.

Comment: I see, so the map $\mathbb Z_p\longrightarrow p^n\mathbb Z_p: x\mapsto p^nx$ will be a group isomorphism since $\mathbb Z_p$ is an integral domain so that its additive subgroup is torsion-free.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what's the difference between Mark's first answer, and second answer? I just don't see why $(\underbrace{0; 0; ...; 0}_{n \text{ elements}}; x_1; x_2; ...) \notin p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$, am I missing something? Isn't it the same as defining $f\left( \sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty a_ip^i \right) = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty a_ip^{i+n}$?

Comment: Dear @Mark, Yes, that's right. User49685, what about $(1,1,\ldots)$? It is supposed to be sent to $(0,0,\ldots,0,1,1,\ldots)$. Is $1\equiv 0\pmod{p^n}$? What you want is $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\mapsto(p^nx_1,p^nx_2,\ldots)=(0,0,\ldots,0,p^nx_{n+1},\ldots)$.